# Dynamic numeric form control issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I add form using jquery append method and this method has `.numerik_kontrol` class but this functions working are another form but it's not working on my dynamic form

my function;

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

    /** numerik kontrol*/
 $(".numerik_kontrol").keydown(function (e) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
             // Allow: Ctrl+A, Command+A
            (e.keyCode === 65 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) || 
             // Allow: home, end, left, right, down, up
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
                 // let it happen, don't do anything
                 return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
 /** numerik kontrol bitiş*/

 /** select seçim*/
$(".btn_ekle").on("click", function(e) {
    var ekle = $(".ekle").html();
    $(".add_after").append(ekle).show();

    e.preventDefault();

});



$(document).on('change', '.havale_tipi', function() {
    var value = $(this).val(),
        parent = $(this).closest(".group");
    if (value == "iban_no") {
        $(".hesaba_form", parent).fadeOut();
        $(".iban_no_form", parent).fadeIn();
    } else {
        $(".iban_no_form", parent).fadeOut();
        $(".hesaba_form", parent).fadeIn();
    }


});



 $(document).on("click", ".iade_sil", function() {

    var form_sil;
    var form_sil = confirm("Formu silmek istediğinize emin misiniz ?");
    if (form_sil == true) {
    $(this).closest(".group").remove(); 
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});

document.getElementById('iade_miktari').className="numerik_kontrol";


});
```

[if you wanna check out full click this link - demo page](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/VjdYWA)

if you click bottom of the form button(left button) you gonna see dynamic forms

Comment: I'll bet you're not creating the dynamic form until after your `$(document).ready` has been called - in which case the `numerik_kontrol` elements will not yet exist - and so the event handler will not be attached to them.  Would need to see more of your code to be sure

Comment: I add my project codepen you can see it there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `$(document).ready` use a `$(document).on` event handler instead of a `keydown` handler on existing `numerik_kontrol` elements.  This will bind the handler to the document and evaluate the selector when every keydown event occurs, instead of directly binding the handler to the result of the single selector evaluation in `$(document).ready`

i.e.

instead of:

```
$(".numerik_kontrol"),keydown(function(e) { ...
```

try something more like this:

```
$document.on("keydown", ".numerik_kontrol", function(e) { ...
```